# Label with text not showing in custom cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom cell set up for UICollectionView. I have a Data model that has an image and title.

I can get the image to show in the cell but cant get the table to show

I tried to set up the label programmatically inside the custom cell (in the same way that the image is set up) yet the image shows but label is invisible...

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

var data: CustomData? {
    didSet {
        guard let data = data else {return}

        bg.image = data.image
        titleLabel.text = data.title

    }

}

fileprivate var titleLabel : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.textAlignment = .left
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.textColor = .black
    label.font = UIFont (name: "Helvetica Neue", size: 30)
    label.text = "random text"
    return label
}()

fileprivate let bg : UIImageView = {

    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pic1")
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    iv.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    iv.layer.masksToBounds = true
    iv.clipsToBounds = true

    return iv
}()

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)
    contentView.addSubview(bg)
    bg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    bg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}                                                                                   

}
```

this is how the custom cell is set up and below how cellForItemAt is setup

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,   cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell

   let color = colorList[indexPath.row]
    cell.backgroundColor = color
    cell.contentView.layer.masksToBounds = true;
    cell.layer.cornerRadius = 12
    cell.clipsToBounds = true
    return cell
     }
```

any ideas where am I going wrong?

Comment: I don't see where are you setting the CustomData to object in the cell?

Comment: You don't apply any constraints to `titleLabel` nor do you give it a frame. Do one of those.

Comment: BTW - your code to give the cell rounded corners should probably be moved to the cell class.

Comment: got it! added frame to titleLabel solved it.

Answer (score 0):

added frame as @rmaddy suggested to titleLable

Comment: Why use constraints for the image and not for the label?

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
titleLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```